# How to change elements inside a vector using insert function and iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, insert, iterator

I would like to change values of a vector with a specified size, using the insert function and iterators.

When I start debugging, Visual Studio shows me this message:

```
Vector iterator not incrementable
```

I have read this is part of the consequence of using `insert` on a vector.

```
vector<int> myvector(10,1);
vector<int>::iterator it;

for (it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); it++)

    myvector.insert(it, 2);
```

Is there an alternative method that allows to pursue the initial purpose?

Comment: Inserting into a vector while you are iterating over it doesn't make sense.  The insert will invalidate the iterator.

Comment: As well as saying "here is what I tried to do, it didn't work", please describe what you are trying to do in something other than non-working code.  Describing the non-working code in English isn't (highly) useful either.  Describe what you are trying to do, *not* only how you are trying to do it.  My guess:  Do you want to turn a vector that contained `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}` to `{2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1` or somesuch?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why Visual Studio gives this confusing message. However, the actual problem here is that insert invalidates iterators - so you can not use it after you inserted anything. The right way to do this is something along following lines:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(10, 1);

    std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    for (; it != vec.end(); ) {
        it = vec.insert(it, 2);
        it += 2;
    }

    for (it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "!: " << *it << "\n";
}
```